# A recommendation for a book on perverse sheaves

Tags: homotopy-theory, textbook-recommendation, perverse-sheaves

I would like to learn about perverse sheaves.

I will be grateful if someone could recommend me a book with the following structure.

1. Introduction to basic homotopy theory (derived category and t-structure)
2. Introduction to sheaves
3. Introduction to perverse sheaves

Comment: The book by Dimca, *Sheaves in Topology* (Universitext, Springer), does that — and many other things.

Comment: Although not a book, Mark Goresky has some notes on his webpage which does all of 1,2 and 3 in the question
https://www.math.ias.edu/~goresky/math2710/index.html.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pramod Achar is working on a book on perverse sheaves and applications in representation theory.  It's a great book!

**EDIT (2021):** The book has now been published by the AMS: 
[Perverse Sheaves and Applications to Representation Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-258/).

Comment: Is it available anywhere?

Comment: It seems that one can obtain a copy of this book by emailing the organizers of this seminar: http://www.math.toronto.edu/jkamnitz/seminar/perverse/perverse.html

Comment: That’s wonderful news!!

Comment: I suggest instead emailing Pramod to ask him for copy.  When I wrote "Please contact the organizers if you want the link to the book", it was intended just for the participants in the seminar.

Comment: With due apologies to everyone else, Pramod is the one person I would trust to write a comprehensible-to-me book on this subject.

Comment: It's a great book!  One thing that you should know is that the book is written with coefficients in arbitrary fields, which makes things a bit more complicated, especially if you are learning the subject for the first time.

Answer (score 6):

Here are two possibilities:

Topological Invariants of Stratified Spaces by Markus Banagl

Intersection Homology & Perverse Sheaves: with Applications to Singularities by Laurenţiu G. Maxim

Answer (score 6):

I'm currently taking a course on perverse sheaves and we are using Kashiwara & Schapira's *Sheaves on Manifolds* (published by Springer). It has all the things you mention and I've found it very readable!